# adding files to git add ignoring directory hierarchy

Tags: git

I have a directory structure like:

```
/parctise1/abc/a.java
/parctise2/abc/b.java
/parctise3/abc/c.java
```

I just want to add file names and avoid adding directory hierarchy(something like below after   executing git add):

```
new file : a.java
new file : b.java
new file : c.java
```

Is there a way we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Git records the tree structure as well as the files' contents.
In your case, root your repo in `/parctise1/abc/` and don't create subdirs.